# R - " cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any' " when using outer(x, f) function

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying plot a 3D perspective of a function, but I'm getting this error when I use `z <- outer(x, egg)`

```
Error in as.vector(x, mode) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'
```

My script:

```
egg <- function(x) {
  return (-(x[2] + 47)*sin(sqrt(abs((x[1]/2) + x[2] + 47))) - x[1]*sin(sqrt(abs(x[1] - (x[2] + 47)))))
}

# Plotting eggholder
x1 <- seq(-512, 512, length.out=100)
x2 <- seq(-512, 512, length.out=100)
x <- c(x1, x2)
z <- outer(x, egg)
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
layout(matrix(1:4, nrow=2))
lapply(c(0,30,60,90), function(t) persp(x1,x2,z, col='blue', theta=t))
```

Comment: You are passing a function to the second argument of `outer` which typically is a vector. The function is the third argument `FUN`. Check `?outer`.

Comment: I tried to pass two vectors and then the function, `> z <- outer(x1, x2, egg)` but I get the error 
**Error in FUN(X, Y, ...) : unused argument (Y)**

Comment: Your function also needs to have two arguments. Currently it only has one.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you figured out how it works, would you mind writing up an answer and posting it here? It's Ok to answer your own question.

Comment: Ok, the answer is posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code that's working. Thanks to LyzandeR.

```
egg <- function(x1, x2) {
  return (-(x2 + 47)*sin(sqrt(abs((x2/2) + x2 + 47))) - 
  x2*sin(sqrt(abs(x1 - (x2 + 47))))) 
}

# Plotting eggholder
x1 <- seq(-512, 512, length.out=100)
x2 <- seq(-512, 512, length.out=100)
z <- outer(x1, x2, egg)
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
layout(matrix(1:4, nrow=2))
lapply(c(0,30,60,90), function(t) persp3D(x1, x2, z, theta=t))
```